# Django how to pass custom variables to context to use in custom admin template?

Tags: django, templates, admin, extends, django-context

I am extending change_list.html and I need to output a variable defined in settings.py.

How do I pass that particular variable into the custom admin template context?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['some_var'] = 'This is what I want to show'
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view