# Django Admin Pass A Variable to base_site.html

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using django-livesettings to save the site title to the database. To be able to access a config value, however, you need to pass the variable to the template via a view:

http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#accessing-your-value-in-a-view

What method of the admin.ModelAdmin class can I override to pass variables to the base_site.html, where the admin site title "Django Site Admin" is located?

This answer may come close but I don't know what it misses:
[Django how to pass custom variables to context to use in custom admin template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220042/django-how-to-pass-custom-variables-to-context-to-use-in-custom-admin-template)

Comment: How about custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) that will add livesettings variables that you need to template context?

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution I found is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36421610/7521854

Essentially, it overrides your admin site's `each_context` method to add as many custom variables as required. The updated context is applied to all admin pages without any further effort.

In my case, I want to have a custom footer displaying release version info. This info is taken from a file which is automatically updated with a `git describe` command during deployment.

File: `app-name/sites.py`:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    """ Extends the default Admin site. """
    site_title = gettext_lazy('My Admin')
    site_header = gettext_lazy('My header')
    index_title = gettext_lazy('My Administration')

    def each_context(self, request):
        version_info = ""
        try:
            version_info = os.environ['RELEASE_TAG']
        except KeyError:
            f = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'assets/version.txt'), 'r')
            version_info = f.read()
            f.close()
            os.environ['RELEASE_TAG'] = version_info

        context = super(MyAdminSite, self).each_context(request)
        context['releaseTag'] = version_info
        return context

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='my_custom_admin')
```

And the related footer tag is:

```
{% block footer %}
<div class="copyright-center">
    <p><small>My Admin {{releaseTag}} Copyright &copy; MyCo</small></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second link is about adding extra variable to the changelist page of a `ModelAdmin`.
The `base_site.html` is extended by many admin pages and thus views, if you want some global change, you need to either extends context of all the relative views or, override the `base_site.html` itself by [setting a variable in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context)

Comment: which view should I add the context variable in?

Comment: @Ygam it depends on your requirement: in which admin page the customization takes effect. You could check `django.contrib.admin.sites.get_urls()` and `django.contrib.admin.options.get_urls()` to find out where the actual admin views reside in. Views such as `index`, `change_view`, `change_list` normally provide API(`extra_context=None` in signature) for adding extra context. You could extend `AdminSite` and `ModelAdmin` to achieve it. If your customization is global, just override the `base_site.html` by copying it to a directory w/ higher priority during template loading, and modify it.