# Adding content to each view(base_site.html) in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I want to pass a list of object to my custom template in Djando admin, **delete_view** and **change_view**. I modified base_site.html for including a nav-bar and I want to pass, from view, a list of objects to the nav-bar.

I did it before for django admin index, changelist_view and add_view as well. I override those function and add the extra content I want.

But I can´t do it in the two firts. The idea should be this one:

```
@csrf_protect_m
@transaction.atomic
def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}                 
    mygetModels = getModels()
    extra_context["modelsTables"] = mygetModels.getTablesModels()
    return super(table_NameAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

As I said that works before in changelist_view, index and add_view. But is not working in **delete_view** and **change_view**.

Comment: Try writing a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), and include it in your admin template. That way, you won't have to override every single admin view just to add some items to the template context.

Comment: Well... Looks better indeed. So I define my function as:
@register.simple_tag
def getTablesModels(self):
Classes = apps.apps.get_models(ddbb)
        modelClasses = []
        for i in xrange(len(Classes)):
            obj = dbModels(Classes[i].__name__.lower(), Classes[i]._meta.db_table)
            modelClasses += [obj]
        return modelClasses
How I call it on My index admin template? Should I import something?
I need to go through all list which this tag is returning
{% for item in modelsTables %}
<li>
a href="/admin/db/{{ item.linkDb }}/">{{ item.nameDb }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, it's impossible to read.

Comment: Hahahaha... lol. Your right. My fault... Anyway, your second approach is better. Cleaner, smarter,... Thanks Alasdair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code you have posted, I'm not sure why your `delete_view` isn't working. I suggest a different approach to add items to the context.

Try overriding your admin site's [`each_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context) method. This avoids having to override multiple model admin methods.

```
def each_context(self, request):
    context = super(MyAdminSite, self).each_context(request)
    context['extra_var'] = 'Extra variable'
    return context
```

If you wanted to use these variables in templates outside of the Django admin, you could write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) or [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

If you are using Django 1.9+, you can use the `simple_tag` decorator 
to save the result of the tag to a variable.

```
{% getTablesModels as modelsTables %}
```

Then you can use the variable in the template

```
{% for item in modelsTables %}
```

Comment: That is what I want. You did it again Alasdair... ;). Thanks Mate.

Comment: What's a good common place to write this `each_context()` override function?

Comment: @NitinNain it’s up to you. The example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) puts the custom site in `my project/admin.py` (next to `settings.py`).

Comment: @NitinNain, I'd use <app-name>/sites.py, cause this is where it is defined originally (admin/sites.py)