# How to change dynamically "Site administration" string in Django's admin?

Tags: django, admin

I want to replace dynamically "Site administration" by a custom string in my admin.
I've already overridden "base.html" for some other purpose, but now I need to pass a variable to this template to replace `{{ title }}` in

```
{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

I've seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220042/django-how-to-pass-custom-variables-to-context-to-use-in-custom-admin-template) that a variable can be passed to the change list template by overriding `changelist_view` and adding an `extra_context` in the model admin, but how can I pass an extra context to the "main" page of the admin"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `index()` view is inside `django.contrib.admin.site.AdminSite` class and supports `extra_context` as well, you could override it, something like:

```
def index(self, *args, **kwargs):
     return admin.site.__class__.index(self, extra_context={'title':'customized title'}, *args, **kwargs)
admin.site.index = index.__get__(admin.site, admin.site.__class__)
```

Also you could override `AdminSite` directly and use `customized_site` instead of `admin.site`:

```
class CustomizedAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def index(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CustomizedAdminSite, self).index(extra_context={...}, *args, **kwargs)
customized_site = CustomizedAdminSite()
```

If you want to have `title` in all Admin pages, better to use [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) or customize some template tag if you can.

Comment: How can I override index() in my admin.py?

Comment: @jul there are ways to do this, just updated the answer by adding some.

Comment: In the end I'm using a context processor. Thanks!

Comment: @okm Isn't passing an arg after a kwarg illegal?

Answer (score 1):

You override the "admin/base_site.html" template:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} | {% trans 'YOUR TITLE HERE' %} {% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'STUFF HERE PERHAPS' %} </h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}

{% endblock %}
```