# How can I extend Django Admin by adding values above the list of model entries?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin, extend

I just started to use Django Admin. I have my code that tells Django Admin to show all entries in `/admin/` page from my model.

I would like to extend the list by adding values above it. I want to display total number of entries that match criteria #1 and total entries that match criteria #2. I don't want to change the list tho. That content is independent.

To get that content, I need to do two queries. This means that I shouldn't do it in the template and I shouldn't just pass the name of template to the attribute `change_list_template`.

The next thing I though was to extend `chnagelist_view`, but capture the response and add my values to it. The only problem is that I think there is a better way; there got to be a better way!

Comment: There is a better way for that than creating extended template. You can add this function through admin.py or models.py

Comment: Okay, I add a function to `admin.py`. Where can I call it so that value of the function is output to Django Admin, above the list?

Comment: Seems to me that `list_display` is per entry. I need to output values above the list of all entries only once.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. I thought it's on the list... I just notice it now when you said above the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research the tricks were to:

1. [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates),
2. [Passing variables to the template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220270/458610),