# How do I pass custom variable values to the django admin interface?

Tags: python, django

I want to do something very simple but I couldn't find any information anywhere: I want to pass some variables to the admin interface of [django](/questions/tagged/django). In simple words, I want to calculate some values:

```
def sum(a,b):
    sum = a + b
    return sum
```

and then use it inside index or base_html.html as `{{ sum }}`

How can I do something like that?

Comment: in django-speak variables in a template are referred to as *context*.  Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220042/django-how-to-pass-custom-variables-to-context-to-use-in-custom-admin-template

Comment: indeed, but I do not want to use "context" from inside a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question.I hope this will help you.
Create this directory structure inside any app.
templatetags
templatetags/**init**.py
templatetags/sum.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_sum(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Now copy a base_site.html inside your template folder from django source code in the structure.

-admin
    -base_site.html 
paste this on the top of html

```
{% load  sum %}
```

now paste this where you want

```
{% with a=10 b=90 %}  
    Sum is here: {% get_sum a b %}
{% endwith %}
```

You can create any function instaed of sum.

Comment: so django sees them as separate .py programs ?

Comment: You can say.See..so many filters and tags are provided by Django itself.Check it in Django Documentation.It depends what u want to do with the template variables.. if its not provided You can create your own template tag in py file. I just give u an example. Do according to your need dude.