# passing variable to javascript in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My admin.ModelAdmin have a media class like this:

```
 class AdminForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
      class Media:
              js = ('admin/js/admin.js', static('js/tags.js'),
                    'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false')
```

But I want to pass variables to the admin.js, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:
Override admin template, pass extra context via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view (see [Django how to pass custom variables to context to use in custom admin template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220042/django-how-to-pass-custom-variables-to-context-to-use-in-custom-admin-template) for code example), and in the template you will have something like this:

```
<script>
    var yourVar = {{ var_from_extra_context }};
</script>
```

Then in your included javascript files you can use these variables.
Note: this code should be before js imports.

Comment: But I am looking for the solution without using custom template. Anyway thanks for the answer.