# Adding context variable into change_view not possible because extra_context not a dictionary

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.7

I would like to add a field on the ModelAdmin.change_view() to filter my inline objects.

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220042/django-how-to-pass-custom-variables-to-context-to-use-in-custom-admin-template) I tried to inject extra_context into it:

```
class ProcessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StepInline,]
    exclude = ('steps',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'name_slug': ('name',)}

    def change_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        print(extra_context)
        extra = extra_context or {}
        extra['filter_form'] = FilterForm()
        return super(ProcessAdmin, self).change_view(request, extra_context=extra)
```

Unfortunately, the method variable `extra_context` is a unicode string and django raises:

```
TypeError, Exception Value: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

on calling `/admin/core/process/5/`.

Is it possible to insert the object_id into the extra_context dictionary to inject a form to filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ModelAdmin.change_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) method has a different signature:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra = extra_context or {}
    extra['filter_form'] = FilterForm()
    return super(ProcessAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
                                                 form_url, extra_context=extra)
```

Comment: Thanks, my fault. [ModelAdmin.changelist_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) has different method arguments.