# Django admin title "Select <model_name> to change"

Tags: django, admin

How can I change the title for Django admin specfic model? 
Automatically it write  "Select  to change"...
I am try each from this options but do nothing:

```
admin.site.site_header = "aaa"
admin.site.site_title = "bbb"
admin.site.index_title = "ccc"
```

Comment: What if you add `verbose_name` in the `Meta` of the model?

Answer (score 2):

You can change this by overriding changelist_view method as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32843287/5413309

```
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['title'] = 'Custom title'
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django admin has no builtin setting that lets you change that title pattern.
What I come up with is this Jquery script that you can put in the *"base.html"* template.
The script strips the original title to the model's verbose name :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var newtitle = $("#content h1").text().replace(/({% trans 'Sélectionnez l’objet' %})/, "")
                                          .replace(/({% trans 'à changer' %})/, "")
                                            .replace(/({% trans 'à afficher' %})/, "");
    //console.log("new title: " + newtitle);
    
    $("#content h1").text(newtitle);
})
```